# How do I loop through and access all sections of returned entries?

Tags: sections

On my search results page I want to add a section filter depending on the different sections that are included in all of the returned entries.

I am getting all the sections like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['inspirationArticles', 'pages', 'pressArticles', 'products']).search(searchQuery).order('score') %}
{% set entrySections = entries.getAllSections() %}
```

And then loop through them:

```
{% for entrySection in entrySections %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

But when trying to access the sections’s names or handles via `{{ entrySection.name }}` or `{{ entrySection.handle }}`, I get a `CException` error:

```
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "handle".
```

So it looks like it isn't actually accessing the SectionModel. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entries to not have a `getAllSections` method. You can use the `group` filter to group your entries by their sections.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section(['inspirationArticles', 'pages', 'pressArticles', 'products']).search(searchQuery).order('score') %}
{% set grouped = entries|group('section') %}

{% for section, entriesInGroup in grouped %}
    <h2>Section: {{ section }}</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entriesInGroup %}
            <li>{{entry}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's some [documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) to help!

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that works like a charm! Though I do kinda wish I could get a way a one less `for loop` to get to the sections’ details, but that's just me being picky ;)